# Strange Things Happening HTML and JS

Tags: html

Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83a54qgo/

I am trying to program an artificial intelligence but have some barriers to pass. It will use pure JS no PHP. For one thing, the "submit" button for some reason keeps wanting to be extremely wide, whereas I want it to form its size to fit the text within. Secondly, in the JS the .innerHTML does not work at all and causes all JS not to function. When commented out, the JS will work, but I am not sure why I cannot get the .innerHTML property of the division with ID "content". Here is the JS file since it won't let me post this without code:

```
var text;
var wrap = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
var add = function(from) {
    alert('This works.');
    if(from === 'user') {
        text = document.getElementById('text').value;
        wrap += "<div class='left'><div class='user'>" + text + "</div></div>";
        text = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: The "button" is actually a div, which will default to 100% width. Fiddle works fine for me if you put fiddle in nowrap - body mode.  NOt sure how it is on your actual site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/83a54qgo/8/

Comment: Don't forget to set, in the jsfiddle configuration panel, Frameworks & Extensions to "No wrap - in <body>".Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/83a54qgo/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You had some error at your code.
So i fixed it.
Take a look to this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/83a54qgo/4/)!

So as to align the whole button as you see ,you have to add  `display:inline-block;` at `.submit` class.

Hope I helped!